# make card payment with paymob in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, card

My goal is to implement a robust solution for card payments in my Flutter app, ensuring that all valid test card information is accepted without any issues.

Steps to Achieve Successful Card Payments:

Choose a Reliable Payment Gateway:
To begin, it is crucial to select a reputable and reliable payment gateway service that offers secure card transaction processing. Some popular choices in the market include Stripe, Braintree, and PayPal. Thoroughly research each option to determine which one best aligns with your specific requirements.

Integrate the Payment Gateway:
Once you have chosen a payment gateway, carefully follow their documentation and guidelines for integrating their SDK or API into your Flutter app. This integration allows you to establish a secure connection with the payment gateway's server and facilitate seamless card payment processing.

Ensure Correct Test Card Information:
When testing the payment functionality, ensure that you are using valid test card information provided by the selected payment gateway. Pay attention to the card number, expiration date, CVV code, and zip code. Incorrect or expired test card information can lead to declined transactions even during testing.

Test in Sandbox or Test Mode:
Most payment gateways offer a sandbox or test mode environment specifically designed for developers to test payment functionality without making actual charges. Enable the test mode in your integration and confirm that you are using the appropriate credentials and endpoints for the testing environment.

Error Handling and Logging:
Implement comprehensive error handling mechanisms in your code to capture any error responses or declined transactions. Utilize logging tools or frameworks to log relevant information for debugging purposes. This will help you identify and resolve any issues that arise during the payment process.